# How to rearrange pandas groupby dataframe output

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

```
ID Sequence    float           Freq     Count
3631 D          1.31              1        1
     P          1.45              1        1
     R          1.44              1        1
3633 D          1.26              3        3
                1.27              2        2
                1.32              1        1
     P          1.33              4        4
```

the above is the output of pandas groupby

```
final_df =  small_df.groupby(['ID','Seq','float'])['ID','Seq'].count()
```

I would like to write this to a csv file as

```
3631,"D,P,R","1.31,1.45,1.44"
3633,"D,P","1.26,1.27,1.32,1.33"
```

would like some help in this research work.
thank you

Comment: So, you don't care about the last 2 columns at all?

Comment: yes,they are not of much use.But that is the way I found to group it in this method .

Comment: See my answer below, and please consider marking it accepted if it was helpful, thanks.

Comment: But this error,final_df.reset_index(level=1).iloc[:, :2].astype(str).groupby(level=0).agg(','.join).to_csv('file.csv', quotechar='"')
  File "/home/smart1/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3026, in reset_index
    new_obj.insert(0, col_name, level_values)
  File "/home/smart1/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2511, in insert
    allow_duplicates=allow_duplicates)
  File "/home/smart1/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3763, in insert
    raise ValueError('cannot insert %s, already exists' % item)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The essence of this problem is just a grouping operation on the `ID`, followed by an `agg`regation with `str.join`.

```
df.reset_index(level=1)\               # reset the first level
  .iloc[:, :2]\                        # select only the first 2 columns
  .astype(str)\                        # convert to string
  .groupby(level=0)\                   # group by the index
  .agg(','.join)\                      # join elements 
  .to_csv('file.csv', quotechar='"')   # save to CSV with a quoting character
```

---

`file.csv`

```
ID,Sequence,float
3631,"D,P,R","1.31,1.45,1.44"
3633,"D,D,D,P","1.26,1.27,1.32,1.33"
```